# Mechanic to find lodgings in settlement: Pathfinder 1e

Tags: pathfinder-1e, downtime

Is there a mechanic in 1st Edition Pathfinder for a party to find good lodgings in a settlement (town/village/city)? I seem to recall reading it somewhere but I can't nail down the source or the exact mechanic.

I think it's something like a *gather information* check to a specified DC, passing = finding a good place and fail = some seedy place.

If anyone knows, would you be able to link the source and the exact rule?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### The Diplomacy skill is a pretty simple way to look for such information.

You could certainly use the *gather information* function of the [Diplomacy skill](http://legacy.aonprd.com/corerulebook/skills/diplomacy.html#diplomacy) to find out about good lodgings in a settlement--but it takes 1d4 hours of game time. Given that most locals will have a pretty good idea where the best lodgings are and have little reason to conceal that information from anyone, I suspect that the DC for such a check would be pretty low in most cases. Failing such a roll generally means that you don't get information, not that you get bad information.

A simpler and less time-consuming (a few rounds) mechanic would be to use Diplomacy to make a request of any random local on the street with an attitude of indifferent or better--which will usually be most people you see. For a relatively small community, your request would fall under "Give simple advice or directions" (a -5 adjustment to DC). In a big city it might fall under "Give detailed advice" (+0 adjustment to DC). Again, getting such common knowledge as where good lodgings are probably doesn't call for a very high DC to the Diplomacy check, though that would ultimately be up to the GM.

As an alternative to Diplomacy, you could use [Intimidate](http://legacy.aonprd.com/corerulebook/skills/intimidate.html#intimidate) against a random local to frighten them into telling you where to find a good inn, but that's probably overkill.

### Using Knowledge, Local would work too.

Alternatively, you could roll for the [Knowledge, Local skill](http://legacy.aonprd.com/corerulebook/skills/knowledge.html#knowledge) to just know the location of good lodgings. According to the knowledge DC table, using K-Local to "Know local laws, rulers, and popular locations" is DC 10. A good place to get a room for the night could certainly fall under "popular locations."